# How to do positioning when using loading.tsx in next js. I need to get it to the center of my screen

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

[this is how I used to add suspense to my web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6l3b3.png)

this is my 'loading.tsx' code ----

```
import React from 'react'

const loading = () => {
    return (
      <div>       
          <span className="loading loading-ring loading-lg"></span>
      </div>
  )
}

export default loading
```

I tried to apply positioning in Tailwind CSS, but I can't arrange that to the center of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using flex-box and are certain that the outer container that is wrapping the `loading.tsx` file is `100%` high, you can use the following:

```
function Loading(): JSX.Element {
  return (
    <div className="h-full w-full flex items-center justify-center">
      <span className="loading loading-ring loading-lg" />
    </div>
  );
}
```